# column template with components functionality

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want a column with checkboxes and the click will call a function in the component.

**NOTICE** that I don't wont to select the row. only call a function.

look at my **first column:**

```
constructor(){
   this.columns = [
            { width: 30,  suppressSorting: true, suppressMenu: true, template: '<input type="checkbox" (change)="updateSelectedList()"/>' },
            { headerName: "Score", field: "severity", filter: 'number' },
            { headerName: "Behaviour tags", field: "tags" },
            { headerName: "Host", field: "host" },
            { headerName: "Time", field: "lastModified" },
            { headerName: "ID", field: "alertId" },
            { headerName: "Assigned", field: "userName", editable: true, cellEditor: "select", cellEditorParams: { values: this.users.map(u => u.userName) } },//},
            { headerName: "Grouped" },
            { headerName: "Comments" }
        ]
}


updateSelectedList(row: RowNode) {
        if (row.isSelected())
            this.checkedAlerts.push(row.data);
        else
            this.checkedAlerts.splice(this.checkedAlerts.indexOf(row.data), 1);
    }
```

the call in the template:

```
<ag-grid-ng2 [rowData]="alerts | listToArray" [columnDefs]="columns" (rowClicked)="$event.api.selectNode($event.node)" (rowSelected)="updateSelectedList($event)" (cellValueChanged)="onUserSelect($event)"></ag-grid-ng2>
```

Comment: That's great, that you **want** that, but please show what you've tried.

Comment: in the question you can see a function in the component called "updateSelectedList" that i want to attach to the change event of the input.

Comment: You still say "I want". StackOverflow is not your unpaid freelancer solution. You show us what you've tried to accomplish the things you want and we will help you to solve the problems you actually encounter.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow. I wrote that I tried to call the "updateSelectedList". but it was never called. I have no other idea what to check.

Comment: You could show us your template for starters :)

Comment: Added a template of the ag-grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column template is fine. By default, ag-grid will select the row when you click on the cell, you can disable that by passing this as one of properties in gridOptions

```
suppressRowClickSelection: false
```